# Implementing IBinarySerialize for CLR aggregate

Tags: c#, serialization, aggregate-functions, clr

I am writing a CLR aggregate that is going to read some fields, save these into two lists of tuples (and also keep track of some values from the input), perform some calculations on these and then return the results. Because I'm working with a list of tuples I can't use Format.Native and as such have to implement IBinarySerialize (as far as I understand). I don't quite understand how to do this though and none of the references I find online go into much detail. This link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.server.ibinaryserialize?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0 Tells me I need to implement the Read(BinaryReader) and Write(BinaryWriter) methods, where the Read(BinaryReader) one has the descirption: "Generates a user-defined type (UDT) or user-defined aggregate from its binary form". But what is the binary form of my list of tuples? How do I read and write from this?

My understanding (possibly incorrect) is that I need to extract all my tuples (and int fields) from the BinaryReader input and create new tuple lists from this data, but I don't know how to go about this. In particular how to read these values from the BinaryReader input.

Code shown below

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using LinearEquationSolver;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;


[Serializable]
[SqlUserDefinedAggregate(
    Format.UserDefined, //use clr serialization to serialize the intermediate result  
    IsInvariantToNulls = true, //optimizer property  
    IsInvariantToDuplicates = false, //optimizer property  
    IsInvariantToOrder = false, //optimizer property  
    MaxByteSize = 8000) //maximum size in bytes of persisted value  
]
public struct LinearEquationSolverAggregate : Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.IBinarySerialize
{
    //List solution
    //Intermediary tuple lists to dynamically store data
    public List<Tuple<int, int, double>> matrixAList;
    public List<Tuple<int, double>> vectorBList;

    public int matrixARowDim;
    public int matrixAColDim;
    public int vectorBSize;

    public void Init()
    {
        this.matrixAList = new List<Tuple<int, int, double>>();
        this.vectorBList = new List<Tuple<int, double>>();

        this.matrixARowDim = 0;
        this.matrixAColDim = 0;
        this.vectorBSize = 0;
    }

    public void Accumulate(int i, int j, double value)
    {

        if (j == - 1) /// j = -1 indicates the row belongs to the B matrix
        {
            //Keep track of vector size
            vectorBSize = Math.Max(i + 1, vectorBSize);

            //List solution
            //Add row to Vector tuple list 
            Tuple<int, double> vectorCell = new Tuple<int, double>(i, value);
            vectorBList.Add(vectorCell);
        }
        else
        {
            //Keep track of matrix dimensions
            matrixARowDim = Math.Max(i + 1, matrixARowDim);
            matrixAColDim = Math.Max(j + 1, matrixAColDim);

            //List solution
            //Add row to Matrix tuple list
            Tuple<int, int, double> matrixCell = new Tuple<int, int, double>(i, j, value);
            matrixAList.Add(matrixCell);

        }
    }

    public void Merge (LinearEquationSolverAggregate Group)
    {
        matrixAList.AddRange(Group.matrixAList);
        vectorBList.AddRange(Group.vectorBList);
        vectorBSize = Math.Max(vectorBSize, Group.vectorBSize);
        matrixARowDim = Math.Max(matrixARowDim, Group.matrixARowDim);
        matrixAColDim = Math.Max(matrixARowDim, Group.matrixAColDim);
    }

    public SqlString Terminate()
    {

        LinearEquationSolverClass thisLinearEquationSolver = new LinearEquationSolverClass(matrixAList.ToArray(), vectorBList.ToArray(), matrixARowDim, matrixAColDim, vectorBSize);
        thisLinearEquationSolver.solveLinearSystemOfEquations();
        double[] x = thisLinearEquationSolver.getSolutionToLinearEquationAsArray();
        return new SqlString(string.Join(";", x));
    }

    public void Read(BinaryReader r)
    {
        
        //What do I put here?

    }

    public void Write(BinaryWriter w)
    {

//What do I put here?

    }


}
```

Comment: Is this really related to the <sql> _language_?

Comment: You should design your binary layout first. Then you create Write / Read methods for the layout so that Read can reconstruct UDT from the binary layout created by Write.

Comment: @Serg can you expand on that? How do I design a binary layout and where in my code would this happen?

Comment: See example in MS docs : [// The binary layout is as follows:
//    Bytes 0 - 19: string text, padded to the right with null characters
//    Bytes 20+: Double value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.server.ibinaryserialize.read?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

Comment: Design your layout at will.

Comment: @Serg Thank you, am I on the right track in thinking then that my Write method need to Write all the data in my struct fields (matrixAList, vectorBList, matrixARowDim, matrixAColDim, vectorBSize) into this binary layout format described in the doc, and then my Read method needs to reconstruct these fields from that format?

Comment: Allthough I gather that the layout in the articly (0-19 strongs, 20+ Double value) is arbitrary and I can contruct the layout in a different way? What are the constraints on the binary layout?

Comment: You are near. For your UDT you should use your own layout. Layout is not a code per se. Just describe it in a similar comments and apply methods to a binary stream accordingly.

Comment: @Serg Can I visualize this process as happening in between the Accumulate steps? So Accumulate is called once, then the data written into the binary layout and so on, and then at the end the Read method write the data back into the UDT format before terminate() is called? Or is the Write method ever called before all the data is stored into the binary format?

Comment: Not quite sure about it. My guess is the optimizer can serialize/deserialize you UDT many times while aggregating the data. We have no control over its behaviour.